# UEFI won't allow me to change boot order

Tags: boot, uefi

So I recently bought a ROG G750JM because my old laptop gave up a few days ago. Since I'm on a strict budget and most of the parts in my old one still work (except for the motherboard) I choose this one instead of others with better hardware spec.

This particular model has a 1 TB HDD drive with the OS installed on it. On my old laptop I had added a 256 MB SSD disk for the OS and other programs and since this one is still under warranty from the supplier I wanted to put this one in my new ROG (I really liked having my OS and programs on an SSD). The problem here is that if I want to run the OS from that particular disk I have to change the boot order. When I get into the boot menu (UEFI BIOS) I can only choose which EFI file I want to run from. I've tried selecting the ones that are available but none of them works. I'm not even allowed to select if I want to boot from CD/DVD/USB/Second Disk or anything.

I don't really know how to proceed from here. Is it possible to change the boot order on a ROG, and if so, how do I do it? Last time I did this on a computer you could select which drive you wanted to boot from, but that option seems to be removed here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Check "Secure Boot" isn't on. With UEFI there are options to revert back to standard boot devices. There may be a swing that says "CSM" alongside "Secure Boot". Select CSM.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Not really sure if it booted from the OS from my old drive or the one that came with the laptop, and there was a number of other issues that arose from this, but the booting worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinnectus answer solved this:

Check "Secure Boot" isn't on. With UEFI there are options to revert back to standard boot devices. There may be a swing that says "CSM" alongside "Secure Boot". Select CSM.